# Do until loop - not a do while(!condition)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a program in Visual Studio, and there is a point in the program when the user will have to mark a item in a ListBox and click on a button to change some values to it. Problem is that it works even if they don't have one marked, and then the program will break at the next button press.

```
if(lbxItems->SelectedIndex < 0)
{
    MessageBox::Show("Please choose an item to change");
}
```

When I do it like this the MessageBox will pop up but the program won't give the user a chance to actually mark an item. I've tried to make it with a `do while` but then it just spammed message boxes until you stopped the program.

The problems is there to begin with because when they click the "change" button the GroupBox in which the ListBox is located disables, so the user can't do it after.
What I think I'm searching for is a way to pause the program in a `do while` loop so the user has time to mark an item before it loops it again and spam more message boxes.

I know this might very well be extremely confusing, and if you need more code, there is plenty more that I can show.

Comment: Disable the button until an item is selected in the listbox, and you won't need to loop at all.

Comment: You can't "pause" in a function like this.  You have to abort the function, let other code run, and then restart the function.

Comment: Ended up making a MouseEnter function that creates a pop up if "lbxItems->SelectedIndex < 0"

Thanks for the help!